# Why isn't my ASP NET web service hosted in Azure doing anything?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I've created an ASP NET web service in VS2019 that when deployed locally connects up to a SQL server hosted on the same machine (which is a virtual machine hosted in an Azure portal) and returns data as an XML file when the `/api/TableName` url is entered. However, after publishing it to the Azure portal, it no longer returns any data and gives a 500 error when I try to get any data through `/api/TableName`. The Azure portal does not have any SQL databases displayed, so I'm assuming the SQL Server is locally hosted on the virtual machine.

What do I need to do here? Do I have to create a new SQL database in Azure and perhaps use a linked server to get to this database on the virtual machine?

This is the guide I followed to create the web service, if that's helpful at all.

https://medium.com/better-programming/building-a-restful-api-with-asp-net-web-api-and-sql-server-ce7873d5b331

Comment: What is the 500 error?

Comment: Does your connection string have a connection to a named instance or simply localhost?

Comment: @AmitJoshi The webpage that loads now, after I redeployed to Azure, is an XML file that says 
`<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
</Error>`
@Jawad The connection string is just the database name, not a URL. I can't connect to the database from SSMS running outside of the virtual machine, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: @Nick You would need to create a new `SQL` instance on your Azure portal which will give you the ability to connect from outside sources (obviously you would need to set the firewall settings). Currently, what you are doing is that you have a local `SQL` server setup. If you cannot connect to SSMS outside the VM, then you need to setup a SQL server in Azure portal.

Comment: If you're simply after a detailed error, I suggest you navigate to the app service in azure portal > Advanced Tools (kudu) > from Menu Tools > Diagnostic Dump. this will contain eventlog.xml which usually contain the error. There's likely also a pathway via the "Diagnostics and solve problems" feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using local SQL Server database while developing the application, however, when you publish it to Azure Web Service, there is no SQL Server installed in it. So, your application will fail to run.

The solutions could be:

1. Make your local SQL Server accessible from public, and update the database connection string accordingly.
2. You can create an Azure VM, and install SQL Server on it, and use it as the first solution.
3. **[Suggested]** You can use [Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/). It is a PaaS service, which you can directly and easily use.